# PHP 5.6 Segmentation fault: 11 (anonnymous function, recursion)

Tags: php

What is wrong with this code? It works when `$it = 1000` but fails with `Segmentation fault: 11` when `$it > 8000`. There is neither **a script timeout** nor **memory exhausted**. Setting high `memory_limit` makes no difference.

```
$it = 10000;
$middleware = function($chain) {
    $chain();
};

$chain = function() use (&$chain, $it, $middleware) {
    static $index = 0;
    if ($index++ < $it) {
        $middleware($chain);
    }
};

$chain();
```

My system is `PHP 5.6.16` with the following extensions:

```
Core, date, ereg, libxml, openssl, pcre, sqlite3, zlib, bcmath, bz2,
calendar, ctype, dom, hash, fileinfo, filter, ftp, gd, gettext, SPL,
iconv, json, ldap, mbstring, session, standard, mysqlnd, pcntl,
mysqli, PDO, pdo_mysql, pdo_sqlite, Phar, posix, Reflection, mysql,
shmop, SimpleXML, soap, sockets, exif, sysvmsg, sysvsem, sysvshm,
tidy, tokenizer, wddx, xml, xmlreader, xmlrpc, xmlwriter, zip, curl,
gmp, igbinary, imap, intl, mcrypt, memcache, memcached, mongo, 
mssql, OAuth, pdo_dblib, pdo_pgsql, pgsql, propro, raphf, readline,  
redis, solr, ssh2, xsl, http, mhash, xdebug
```

Comment: Argh, please start using varying variable names instead of just `$chain` everywhere, it makes it rather painful to parse.

Comment: The Segmentation fault indicates the server has run out of memory. That's why it works until '$it > 8000'. Literally a stack overflow condition.

Comment: It does not run out of memory. The memory level it takes is much lower than maximum allowed by php

Comment: Do you have xdebug enabled?

Comment: Yes I can enable xdebug, no difference. xdebug only fires when ``xdebug.max_nesting_level`` i lower than ``$it``

Comment: note that the call stack is only part of the memory used by the program, and will be exhausted long before reaching `memory_limit`

Comment: Stackoverflow. You have to restructure your design.

Comment: Can It be increased somehow? ``10000`` iterations is **very** limiting. I have a recent machine with plenty of available memory and CPU power.

Comment: That's the *wrong* approach.

Comment: it runs fine in the [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cabba73e84197bb743053b1b0e88c476591fada0) have you tried running it on a fresh php install with just php? Then slowly add extensions until the code fails. And then you can figureout what limits it. Or vice versa and disable plugins one by one until it runs

Comment: Segmentation fault DOESN'T ALWAYS indicates that the server has run out of memory. There are several possible reasons exists behind a SIGSEGV. Most common two reasons are a bug in running application/library/extension code (php with loaded extensions for this case) and/or hardware failure. For example, more than 20+ segfault related bugs are fixed between PHP 5.6.13 and 5.6.16 This is really weird situation. You can try to create a coredump and investigate the problem in depth. Another option is simply reducing the batch size of iteration (this means you have to restructure your design).

Comment: Getting a segmentation fault due to high nesting level of function calls is PHP's buggy way to handle a stack overflow. The problem is basically the C body of PHP, which assumes that there is always enough stack and thus doesn't provide any means to detect, signal or handle the case that you run out of stack memory.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the PHP version? Anytime i get segmentation faults i switch to PHP 7.0 and suddenly there's an accurate error message. I fix the error and switch back to PHP 5.6 and it works again.
Maybe your callback throws an exception and the error handler crashes.